# How do I show that $(-1)^n\cos(n\pi)$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

taking the limit of $(-1)^n\cos(n\pi)$

I know that it diverges but would an answer be that since the domain is $-1 < x < 1$ valid? Or what else do I need to say to prove that it is divergent?

Comment: I believe you meant to say that the sequence is contained in the interval $[-1, 1]$. So, the sequence is bounded. But this says nothing about whether it diverges.

Comment: Have you written out the first few terms?

Comment: i have yes, it oscillates between -1 and 1, like term one is 0.999, term two is -0.998, term three is 0.988 and it goes up and down

Comment: would that just be a valid arguement to say that it is diverges because it oscillates ?

Comment: Looks like you're depending a little heavily on a crappy calculator. For example, if $n=1$ then $(-1)^1 \cos(1 \cdot \pi) = -1 \cdot \cos(\pi) = -1 \cdot -1 = +1$ on the nose, not $0.999$.

Comment: Hope you've switched your calculator to take the argument in *radians*, not in *degrees*. If not, can you please do?

Comment: I've removed my previous comment about the calculator being faulty. It sounds like Stinking Bishop is correct that you were incorrectly using your calculator in degrees instead of radians.

Answer (score 5):

The sequence is convergent.

Note that $\cos n\pi$ is just another way to write $(-1)^n$, so in fact every term of the sequence is $1$.

(I assume here you intend for $n$ to take positive integer values, so this is in fact a sequence.)

---

<strike>(In fact, $(-1)^n$ isn’t a real number for any real values of $n$ except for integers.)</strike>

[Correction: $(-1)^n$ isn’t a real number for all but a countable number of real values of $n$.]

Comment: So, just in case,$(-1)^n\cos(n\pi)=(-1)^{2n}=1,\forall n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct, @VerkhovtsevaKatya

Comment: $(-1)^{1/3} = -1$ since $(-1)^3 = -1$.

Comment: @martycohen : Yes, I wrote too hastily. Removing that assertion.